# Objective c calling method with argument into another method

Tags: objective-c

How can i call method with arguments into another method.

I have a problem in objective c class. 
My code is

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {

    location.coordinate.longitude];    
    googleUrl=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place /search/xml?location=%f,%f&radius=500&name=the%20money&sensor=false&  key=AIzaSyCcC9pmri9XGOgyhjoHQq37cmcfgsfb6bBZe80",location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude];

}



-(void)ParseXML_of_Google_PlacesAPI {

    NSURL *googlePlacesURL = [NSURL  URLWithString:googleUrl];

    NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:googlePlacesURL];
}
```

I  want to put googleUrl value in parseXML method

Answer (score 3):

You can change the signature of your parseXML_of_Google_PlacesAPI method as follows:

```
-(void) ParseXML_of_Google_PlacesAPI: (NSString*) googleUrl {...}
```

Furthermore, modify the implementation of the method as:

```
NSURL *googlePlacesURL = [NSURL URLWithString:googleUrl];
return [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:googlePlacesURL];
```

Then, you might call the method as follows:

```
// your previous code with the location
NSData* googleData = [self ParseXML_of_Google_PlacesAPI:googleUrl];
```

Couple of points:
- The convention for method names is that it starts with a lowercase letter. 
- On the higher level, what you are trying to do is to encapsulate certain functionality within a method (parseXML). This is a very good practice as it will make your code more readable. One thing to be careful about is to pick good method names; I would pick getXMLDataOfURL:(NSString*) url as the method name. That would clearly identify what you are trying to achieve in this method. 
- A healthy discussion for best practices regarding methods can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250284/best-practices-many-small-functions-methods-or-bigger-functions-with-logical-pr)

Comment: Method names starting with `get…` usually take a pointer parameter that they use to store a result, cf. [`-[NSData getBytes:range:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-CIACCFDG).

Comment: Thanks @gcbrueckmann, this was something that I didn't know before. Will update my code as well!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is somewhat unclear. I'm assuming that you're asking how you can pass the googleUrl value from the locationUpdate method to the ParseXML_of_Google_PlacesAPI method.

If that's the case, then you'll need to add a NSString parameter to the signature of the latter method.

```
-(void) ParseXML_of_Google_PlacesAPI:(NSString *) googleUrl { ... }
```

You can then invoke this method by using the following syntax from the locationUpdate method:

```
[self ParseXML_of_Google_PlacesAPI:googleUrl];
```

Does that help?

(btw, if you do this, there's probably no need to set googleUrl as an ivar/property. Just declare it as a NSString in the scope of the locationUpdate method.)