# Is it bad form to exclude godocs on exported names?

Tags: go, comments, godoc

According to "Effective Go" [golang.org/doc/effective_go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#commentary)

> Every exported (capitalized) name in a program should have a doc comment.

Let's say I have a view handler on a simple web application

```
// Handle the front page of the website
func FrontPageView(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    controllers.RenderBasicPage(w, "frontPage") 
}
```

My question is this: is that godoc *really* necessary? Perhaps I'm just in love with Robert Martin's Clean Code right now, but it seems an effectively named variable, in this case `FrontPageView` removes the need for such a godoc. This is probably a derivative/duplicate of "are javadocs necessary?" or "are python docstrings necessary?", but I do want to make sure that when learning a new language I'm sticking to the language-specific canonical ways-to-do-things.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that [**golint**](https://github.com/golang/lint) would tell you that the doc for FrontPageView() must start with

```
// FrontPageView ...
```

And yes, it is good practice to include (here a short) comment on all exported methods, functions, as described also in "[Go Code Review Comments](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/CodeReviewComments)".

> Comments documenting declarations should be full sentences, **even if that seems a little redundant**.
>   This approach makes them format well when extracted into godoc documentation.
>
> Comments should begin with the name of the thing being described and end in a period:

```
// A Request represents a request to run a command.
type Request struct { ...

// Encode writes the JSON encoding of req to w.
func Encode(w io.Writer, req *Request) { ...
```

---

> it's my understanding that effectively clean code means keeping functions simple with a name that describes the function's one role;

Then the doc can include edge cases (even if in your case there are none).
In any case, adding a short doc won't make it "less clean".

> as they get more complex you split them into multiple, equally simple, functions.

I use [**gocyclo**](https://github.com/fzipp/gocyclo) for this: any [cyclomatic complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/250314/6309) above 10, and I split the function.

> Also, changes would require an update in the godoc as well as the name

That is the idea: keeping the doc in sync (and `golint` helps)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a couple of reasons to write doc comments:

- Lint. If you use `golint`, it will print warnings on every exported method that has no doc comment. If you have a lot of those you can accidentally miss something that should actually be documented. Having zero `golint` warnings in your code allows you to react quickly when the docs are missing somewhere or you have other style inconsistencies.
- Changes. The code changes all the time. Maybe now your `FrontPageView` is a one-liner with no content, but in the future it might become more complex, so you'll have to add a doc comment anyway to explain, what's going on.
- Grep. In your example, if I am a new developer and I'm given a task having to do with the front page, I will probably do `godoc pkg | grep 'front page'` or `git grep 'front page'`. If you don't provide a doc comment, both of those will probably be useless for me, and I'll have to either launch the godoc web interface to look for it with my eyes, or try a few other greps.

Comment: Right, so I haven't been using `golint`, and will be doing so from now on (Thank you and VonC for pointing that out), but on your bit about changes - it's my understanding that effectively clean code means keeping functions simple with a name that describes the function's one role; as they get more complex you split them into multiple, equally simple, functions. Also, changes would require an update in the godoc as well as the name.