# Log4J - Test log level useful?

Tags: java, log4j

I am doing a code review and I would like your thought about a small piece of code:

```
if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
{
    logger.debug("debug log");
}
```

Is there a real reason/benefit of doing the test `if(logger.isDebugEnabled())` ?

Why not just write `logger.debug("debug log");` without the test ?

Comment: Did you try to look for it before asking? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963492/in-log4j-does-checking-isdebugenabled-before-logging-improve-performance

Comment: @baraky Yes it's exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for the link (didn't find it before posting my question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not useful for the example that you provided. But it can be useful if you include other data in the log line, for example:

```
logger.debug("Info: " + someObject.getSomeInformation());
```

Note that the method `getSomeInformation` will be called on `someObject` before `logger.debug` is called, whether the level is debug or not. Also, a string concatenation will be performed. To avoid the cost of the method call and string concatenation, you can put this in an `if` like in your question.

Comment: `Note that the method getSomeInformation will be called on someObject before logger.debug` I didn't know about that. Indeed now I can see the difference. Thanks for your insight ;)