# Should python debug statements etc be wrapped by if debug?

Tags: java, python, logging

Coming from Java, it is advisable to wrap a log.debug with

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled())
    log.debug("blah blah blah "+someObject+" more blahs than you can blah at"):
```

Is there a similar reson to do this in python? Or does python handle strings differently?

Comment: Out of curiosity, *why* is it advisable? Maybe then we could tell you if those reasons apply to Python.

Comment: Is there a ... yes! Here, an SO question for java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963492/in-log4j-does-checking-isdebugenabled-before-logging-improve-performance. Effectively, it is a typical simple performance optimization. Ugh, i guess my trivial example wasn't quite right... let me fix

Comment: @bharal, thanks for clarifying what do you really mean - I've updated the answer, recheck it, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for additional checks. Just configure your [logging level](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel):

```
>>> import logging
>>> root = logging.getLogger()
>>> root.setLevel(logging.INFO)
>>> root.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
>>> logging.error("test")
test
>>> logging.debug("test")
>>>
```

Again, there is no need for additional checks (the source code taken from `logging/__init__.py`):

```
class Logger(Filterer):
    ...
    def debug(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Log 'msg % args' with severity 'DEBUG'.

        To pass exception information, use the keyword argument exc_info with
        a true value, e.g.

        logger.debug("Houston, we have a %s", "thorny problem", exc_info=1)
        """
        if self.isEnabledFor(DEBUG):
            self._log(DEBUG, msg, args, **kwargs)
```

As you can see logging itself makes the check.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just found this on the hunt for python equivalent ifdef debug; exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 3):

The suggested answer ignores the overhead of string concatenation and any heavy method calls.

So this:

```
log.debug("blah blah blah "+someObject+" more blahs than you can blah at")
```

Will cost the string contact, even in ERROR logging level.

Different languages/loggers manage that in different ways, checking for isDebugEnabled() or isEnabledFor() are good best practices.

Of course, you shouldn't pre-optimize if this is not relevant, like anything in this world.