# Is it possible to programmatically disable log4j for one method and methods it will call?

Tags: java, log4j, profiling

There is huge web app. When user interact with web application, most of functions are called only once, so there are no performance issues.
I wrote new "import from file" method which calls many times different methods from system. I don't want to modify methods of other people nor disable log4j. Import from file will be used rarely and is treated like add-on, not major functionality.
I run into performance problems, because of this.
After profiling I found out that almost 22% of time is used by log4j.

Is it possible to programmatically disable log4j for one method and methods it will call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think for performance reasons you should replace calls like this:

```
 log.debug("some informantion: " + objA);
```

with this:

```
if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
   log.debug("some informantion: " + objA);
}
```

OR else you can use a FormatLogger class like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/105908/548225

#### EDIT

To programmatically disable logging, you can use code like this:

```
Logger.getLogger("your.logger.name").setLevel(Level.OFF);
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Comment: I don't want to modify methods of other people. Is it really big system and it will impact all it functionality just because of rarely used import method.

Comment: Pls see my EDIT section to disable logging programmatically.

Comment: For performance reasons ? Logger.debug() already do the `isDebugEnabled()` check so for performance reasons, you should NOT do the check youself ;-) .   See http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.14/org/apache/log4j/Category.java#Category.debug%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: @Imo Using `if` you do not need to evaluate variables/methods and the whole string concat. Same reason why Log4J2 now has support for lambdas to delay the evaluation