# php class function wrapper

Tags: php, oop

this is my class:

```
class toyota extends car {
    function drive() {
    }
    function break() {
    }
}

class car {
    function pre() {
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can do so that when I run $car->drive(), $car->break() (or any other function in toyota), it would call $car->pre() first before calling the functions in toyota?

Comment: Read up on "constructor" functions...that may be what you need.

Comment: Can you please clarify?  I can't tell if you want to run $car->pre() whenever you create a new object, or anytime you call a method of $car.  The answers below cover both - I just don't know which one to mod up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yep. You could use `protected` and some `__call` magic:

```
class toyota extends car {
    protected function drive() {
        echo "drive\n";
    }
    protected function dobreak() {
        echo "break\n";
    }
}

class car {
    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        if (method_exists($this, $name)) {
            $this->pre();
            return call_user_func_array(array($this, $name), $args);
        }


    }

    function pre() {
        echo "pre\n";
    }
}

$car = new toyota();
$car->drive();
$car->dobreak();
```

http://ideone.com/SGi1g

Comment: Not only is this the only answer that uses __call (the right way to do it) but it also is the only one that actually does some method_exists check and actually calls the originally called method to begin with.  Do this!

Comment: Do you mean private instead of protected? Cause protected can still be visible by parent and inherited.

Comment: @sberry, checking with method_exists() will hide the default error received when calling invalid methods

Comment: @Starx: yep, but in case of not existent method you could throw native error or exception

Comment: @Patrick: nope, `private` won't work, because parent class doesn't have an access to the ancestor's private methods

Comment: You're right. But I tried protect and it doesn't work too. It says: Fatal error: Call to protected method

Comment: I think it doesn't work because __call only executed if the function doesn't exist.

Comment: @Patrick: If you go to http://ideone.com/SGi1g you will see that it works. Most likely that you've done something wrong

Comment: Some places it works but some it doesn't. This is the error it returns Fatal error: Call to protected method toyota::drive() from context ''. Any idea what that could mean? my php version is 5.2.8, is that the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following, but I don't think that is what you want.

```
class toyota extends car {
    function drive() {
         $this->pre();
    }
    function break() {
         $this->pre();
    }
}

class car {
    function pre() {
    }
}
```

You may want to look into PHP specific magic methods. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Answer (score 0):

This will better done with the magic methods called __call()

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    $this -> pre();
    return $this -> $name($arguments);
}
```

**What is this method?** It overrides the default method call, so that `preCall` State can be invoked.

Your `toyota` class

```
class toyota extends car {    

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        $this -> pre();
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $name), $arguments);
    }

    function drive() {
    }
    function break() {
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this -> $name($arguments)` --- will call the requested method with all the parameters passed as an array. So `$car->drive(1, 2)` will be re-called with `$car->drive(array(1, 2))` which is just incorrect

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP5 (>=5.3.2), there is a solution that works with declaring all methods as private. This will enforce method call from single function call:

```
exec_method()
```

To run at: http://ideone.com/cvfCXm

The code snippet is here:

```
<?php

    class car {

        //method to get class method
        public function get_method($method_name) {
            $class = new ReflectionClass(get_class($this));
            $method = $class->getMethod($method_name);
            $method->setAccessible(true);
            return $method;
        }

        public function exec_method($method_name, $arg_args=array()) {

            //execute the pre() function before the specified method
            $this->pre();

            //execute the specified method
            $this->get_method($method_name)->invokeArgs($this, $arg_args);
        }

        public function pre() {
            echo 'pre';
            echo '<br />';
        }
    }

    class toyota extends car {
        private function drive() {
            echo 'drive';
            echo '<br />';
        }

        private function brake() {
            echo 'brake';
            echo '<br />';
        }
    }

    $toyota = new toyota();
    $toyota->exec_method('drive');
    $toyota->exec_method('brake');
?>
```

Reference:

[Answer to Best practices to test protected methods with PHPUnit [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2798203/46971)

Answer (score -2):

Just add a [constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), like this...

```
class toyota extends car {
    function __construct() { 
        $this->pre();
    }   

    function drive() {
        echo "drive!";
    }

    function dobreak() {
        echo "break!";
    }
}

class car {
    function pre() {
        echo "Hello!";
    }
}

$car = new toyota();
$car->drive();
$car->dobreak();
```

> Classes which have a constructor method call this method on each
>   newly-created object, so it is suitable for any initialization that
>   the object may need before it is used.

`break` is reserved, so you shouldn't use this as a function name.

Comment: i think he is looking for a way to run the method `pre` prior to a function call, not on object initialization

Comment: While replying I was interrupted. I've updated my example with the constructor. it still does the job.