# How do I access private attributes in PHP?

Tags: php, unit-testing, reflection, phpunit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best practices to test protected methods with PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249664/best-practices-to-test-protected-methods-with-phpunit)

```
class Footer
{
  private $_isEnabled;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->_isEnabled = true;
  }

  public function disable(){
    $this->_isEnabled = false;
  }  
}
```

When I am writing a unit test for the disable function after I set `_isEanabled` to false, I want to assert whether or not it is false.

But how can I access `$_isEnabled`?

This is my test function:

```
public function testDisable(){
  $footer = new Footer();
  $footer->disable();
  $this->assertFalse($footer->_isEnable);
}
```

Comment: I think this question should be reopened, there is a link in the comments of the accepted answer describing how to do this via reflection that can be turned into a real answer, and also the duplicate questions don't seem to exist any more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:

You cannot. That's what PRIVATE means...

Long answer:

You can do it using reflection:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

It is a bit complicated, though, and adds another layer prone to fail so it is not the best way for testing...

I rather prefer to create a getter function:

```
public function getEnabled() {
   return $this->_isEnabled;
}
```

But if you have not done it as simple, I think you do not want to create it... but given the alternatives, you may reconsider it.

Comment: Yes I know it.. This example is a simple one.. but the real one is more complex.. I want to get access to the private attributes. I did it for private methods using reflection class. But don't knw how to do it for attributes.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php

Answer (score 1):

An accessible property has to be public, I think that is self explanatory. However, you might encounter code where protected and private properties seem accessible in a way similar to accessing public variables.

This is done using the magic getter method:

```
class Footer
{
    private $_isEnabled;

    public function __get($propName)
    {
        if (!isset($this->{$propName}))
        {
            throw new Exception($propName.' is not set');
        }
        return $this->{$propName};
    }
}
```

This magic method is invoked each time you try to access a property that either, doesn't exist or isn't public. In short:

```
$instance->_isEnabled;//will work.
```

You can alter this method as you like, so that, for example, the underscore isn't required anymore... there's tons of things you can do with this.
Refer to the [man pages](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt getting points by this: the class is not "algebraically" complete. A `public function isEnabled()` is missing. If the unit test has no info about the state, then other class clients will also miss this info.

A unit test on something private does not help saying anything on the public API, but checks internal operation which *should* be obvious.

In general it is bad business having unit tests relying on the implementation; then reimplementation makes maintaining unit tests too.