# Php: how to make private static method to public, and class cannot be insantized?

Tags: php, reflection

```
abstract class MyClass
{
    private static makeMePublic()
    {
    }
}
```

I want to make MyClass::makeMePublic method to be callable from the outside. I saw a solution here: [Best practices to test protected methods with PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249664/best-practices-to-test-protected-methods-with-phpunit) but that requires the class to be instantized. In this case its not possible. So, how to make "public" this method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[The docs say](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invokeargs.php) you can just pass `null` as the first param to `invokeArgs` to execute a static method.

```
protected static function getMethod($name) {
  $class = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');
  $method = $class->getMethod($name);
  $method->setAccessible(true);
  return $method;
}

public function testMakeMePublic() {
  $foo = self::getMethod('makeMePublic');
  $foo->invokeArgs(null, $args);
  ...
}
```