# Should Private/Protected methods be under unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

In TDD development, the first thing you typically do is to create your interface and then begin writing your unit tests against that interface. As you progress through the TDD process you would end-up creating a class that implements the interface and then at some point your unit test would pass.

Now my question is about the private and protected methods that I might have to write in my class in support of the methods/properties exposed by the interface:

- Should the private methods in the class have their own unit tests?
- Should the protected methods in the class have their own unit tests?

My thoughts:

- Especially because I am coding to interfaces, I shouldn't worry about protected/private methods as they are black boxes.
- Because I am using interfaces, I am writing unit tests to validate that the contract defined is properly implemented by the different classes implementing the interface, so again I shouldnt worry about the private/protected methods and they should be exercised via unit tests that call the methods/properties defined by the interface.
- If my code-coverage does not show that the protected/private methods are being hit, then I don't have the right unit-tests or I have code thats not being used and should be removed.

Comment: If you don't exercise your protected methods from your tests, either by overriding them, or by calling them, why are they protected, rather than private?  By making them protected you're making a conscious decision to expose the extension point / functionality.  To me, if you're following TDD, this decision should be driven by the tests you're writing.

Comment: You should put the part about your own thoughts in a separate answer. Let me know when you do and I will upvote.

Comment: Same for private only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105007/should-i-test-private-methods-or-only-public-ones

Comment: You're correct about active unit tests, i.e., those that are setup to run continuously. For these, you only want public and protected interfaces to be tested. You can and could benefit from also writing tests for private methods. Those tests shouldn't be part of your continuous suite, but as a one off to verify your implementation is good it can be a highly valuable tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test a class that has private methods, fields or inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-do-i-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

No, I don't think of testing private or protected methods.  The private and protected methods of a class aren't part of the public interface, so they don't expose public behavior.  Generally these methods are created by refactorings you apply after you've made your test turn green.

So these private methods are tested *implicitly* by the tests that assert the behavior of your public interface.

On a more philosophical note, remember that you're testing behavior, not methods.  So if you think of the set of things that the class under test can do, as long as you can test and assert that the class behaves as expected, whether there are private (and protected) methods that are used internally by the class to  implement that behavior is irrelevant.  Those methods are implementation details of the public behavior.

Comment: I like the fact that you said that unit tests, test the behavior and not the methods! That clarifies things a whole lot.

Comment: I agree with @rajah. That should be the first statement on every tutorial. I've been wondering how to test my methods, now I know I need not to. +1

Comment: Would you say this still applies in cases where base classes implement protected behaviour the public are expected to inherit and use? Then the protected methods are still part of the public interface, are they not?

Comment: Generally speaking, patterns that favor separation of concerns are more suitable to isolated unit tests while patterns that favor encapsulation have easier to use APIs.

Comment: This doesn't clear up the case of protected visibility. It seems a protected method is also part of an interface, often, it's an extension point, purposely made protected to be such. I'd say in those cases, you should unit test them also. You don't want anyone changing things in the future and breaking classes that depended on those extension points for behavior.

Answer (score 64):

I disagree with most of the posters.

The most important rule is: WORKING CODE TRUMPS THEORETICAL RULES about public/protected/private.

Your code should be thoroughly tested.  If you can get there by writing tests for the public methods, that sufficiently exercise the protected/private methods, that's great.

If you can't, then either refactor so that you can, or bend the protected/private rules.

There's a great story about a psychologist who gave children a test.  He gave each child two wooden boards with a rope attached to each end, and asked them to cross a room w/o touching their feet to the floor, as fast as possible.  All the kids used the boards like little skis, one foot on each board, holding them by the ropes, and sliding across the floor.  Then he gave them the same task, but using only ONE board.  They pivoted/"walked" across the floor, one foot on each end of the single board -- and they were FASTER!

Just because Java (or whatever language) has a feature (private/protected/public) does not necessarily mean you are writing better code because you use it!

Now, there will always be ways to optimize/minimize this conflict.  In most languages, you can make a method protected (instead of public), and put the test class in the same package (or whatever), and the method will be available for test.  There are annotations that can help, as described by other posters.  You can use reflection to get at the private methods (yuck).

The context also matters.  If you're writing an API for use by external people, public/private is more important.  If it's an internal project -- who really cares?

But at the end of the day, think about how many bugs have been caused by lack of testing.  Then compare to how many bugs have been caused by "overly visible" methods.  That answer should drive your decision.

Comment: If a method is critical, and has a complicated logic, asserting it's behavior is very useful in preventing bugs. Writing a unit test for such a method can even help as you are implementing the method in a sort of exploratory way. So even if it's private, I'd say it's worth unit testing. BUT, and there's a big but, you must remember tests are code coupling. If you write test to a method, you're preventing refactoring.

Comment: So before you go about writing tests for private methods, I'd say always rethink your design. See if things can be generalized and turned into pure functional methods. If so, you can extract them into their own construct. This construct can then have it's own public interface and be unit tested. Remember, often times, complicated behavior in private methods might be a sign of a class having more then a single responsibility. So please, rethink your design first.

Comment: Yeah but what is "working code"? Testing a private method says nothing about whether or not your object has the right behavior. That's the main point of why we only test the public methods. Only public methods exhibit behavior that the user of a piece of code cares about.

Comment: "Working code" is code that works.  If there's a bug in your private (or quasi-private) method, that is not caught by the tests for your public method(s), then something's wrong.  Maybe your design is wrong, fair enough: I agree that the best solution are tests that call the public methods.

But that's not always possible, especially if you're adding to or fixing legacy code.  (I speak from experience, on a project with 1 million lines of code.)  Tested code is always better than untested code, period.  Even if we have break nice rules about only testing public methods!

Comment: The bit (at the top) about "tests are code coupling... preventing refactoring" is 100% wrong.  In the architectural metaphor, tests are scaffolding, not concrete.  Things change, tests change, get thrown out, new tests get written.  I agree good design minimizes test rewrites.  But change happens, even to the best designs.

Comment: I have a good example where I set an option using builder pattern.

The private method that consumes this option is 3 levels deep below the public method and simply calls a function if the option is true.

This code needs to be tested, and isn't possible to test the functionality via the public method.

This proves to me that ignoring private methods isn't feasible.

Answer (score 35):

You wrote:

> In TDD development, the first thing
>   you typically do is to create your
>   interface and then begin writing your
>   unit tests against that interface. As
>   you progress through the TDD process
>   you would end-up creating a class that
>   implements the interface and then at
>   some point your unit test would pass.

Please let me rephrase this in [BDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development) language:

> When describing why a class is valuable and how it behaves, the first thing you typically
>   do is to create an example of how to use the class, often via its interface*. As you add
>   desired behavior you end up creating a class which provides that value, and then at some
>   point your example works.
>
> *May be an actual `Interface` or simply the accessible API of the class, eg: Ruby
>   doesn't have interfaces.

This is why you don't test private methods - because a test is an example of how to use the class, and you can't actually use them. Something you can do if you want to is delegate the responsibilities in the private methods to a collaborating class, then mock / stub that helper.

With protected methods, you're saying that a class which extends your class should have some particular behavior and provide some value. You could then use extensions of your class to demonstrate that behavior. For instance, if you were writing an ordered collection class, you might want to demonstrate that two extensions with the same contents demonstrated equality.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant post. Clarifies a lot.

Answer (score 24):

When you're writing the unit tests for your class, you shouldn't necessarily care whether or not the functionality of the class is implemented directly in the method on the public interface or if it is implemented in a series of private methods.  So yes, you should be testing your private methods, but you shouldn't need to call them directly from your test code in order to do so (directly testing the private methods tightly couples your implementation to your tests and makes refactoring unnecessarily hard).

Protected methods form a different contract between your class and its future children, so you should really be testing it to a similar extent as your public interface to ensure that the contract is well defined and exercised.

Comment: +1 for saying that "protected methods form a contract between the base class and its children", those should be really tested. While private methods themselves may be just implementation details of public methods so they shouldn't be necessarily tested

Answer (score 13):

No!  Only test interfaces.

One of the big benefits of TDD is assuring that the interface works no matter how you've chosen to implement the private methods.

Answer (score 12):

Completing what others said above, I would say that protected methods are part of an interface of some kind: it simply happens to be the one exposed to inheritance instead of composition, which is what everyone tends to think about when considering interfaces.

Marking a method as protected instead of private means it is expected to be used by third party code, so some sort of contract needs to be defined and tested, as happens with normal interfaces defined by public methods, which are open both for inheritance and composition.

Answer (score 10):

There's two reasons for writing tests:

1. Asserting expected behavior
2. Preventing regression of behavior

**The take on (1) Asserting expected behavior:**

When you're asserting expected behavior, you want to make sure the code works as you think it should. This is effectively an automated way of doing your routine manual verification that any dev would perform when implementing any kind of code:

- Did what I just write works?
- Does this loop actually end?
- Is it looping in the order I think it is?
- Would this work for a null input?

Those are questions we all answer in our heads, and normally, we'd try to execute the code in our heads too, make sure it looks like it does work. For these cases, it is often useful to have the computer answer them in a definitive manner. So we write a unit test that assert it does. This gives us confidence in our code, helps us find defects early, and can even help actually implementing the code.

It's a good idea to do this wherever you feel is necessary. Any code that is a little tricky to understand, or is non trivial. Even trivial code could benefit from it. It's all about your own confidence. How often to do it and how far to go will depend on your own satisfaction. Stop when you can confidently answer Yes to: Are you sure this works?

For this kind of testing, you don't care about visibility, interfaces, or any of that, you only care about having working code. So yes, you would test private and protected methods if you felt they needed to be tested for you to answer Yes to the question.

**The take on (2) Preventing regression of behavior:**

Once you've got working code, you need to have a mechanism in place to protect this code from future damage. If nobody was to ever touch your source and your config ever again, you wouldn't need this, but in most cases, you or others will be touching the source and the configs of your software. This internal fiddling is highly likely to break your working code.

Mechanisms exist in most languages already as a way to protect against this damage. The visibility features are one mechanism. A private method is isolated, and hidden. Encapsulation is another mechanism, where you compartmentalize things, so that changing other compartments doesn't affect others.

The general mechanism for this is called: coding to boundary. By creating boundaries between parts of the code, you protect everything inside a boundary from things outside of it. The boundaries become the point of interaction, and the contract by which things interact.

This means that changes to a boundary, either by breaking it's interface, or breaking it's expected behavior, would damage and possibly break other boundaries which relied on it. That's why it's a good idea to have a unit test, that targets those boundaries and assert they don't change in semantic and in behavior.

This is your typical unit test, the one most everybody talks about when mentioning TDD or BDD. The point is to hardened the boundaries and protect them from change. You do not want to test private methods for this, because a private method is not a boundary. Protected methods are a restricted-boundary, and I would protect them. They aren't exposed to the world, but are still exposed to other compartments or "Units".

**What to make of this?**

As we've seen, there's a good reason to unit test public and protected methods, as to assert our interfaces don't change. And there's also good reason to test private methods, as to assert our implementation works. So should we unit test them all?

Yes and No.

**Firstly**: Test all methods that you feel you need a definitive proof that it works in most cases as to be able to be confident your code works, no matter the visibility. Then, disable those tests. They've done there job.

**Lastly**: Write tests for your boundaries. Have a unit test for each point that will be used by other units of your system. Make sure this test assert the semantic contract, method name, number of arguments, etc. And also make sure the test asserts the available behavior of the unit. Your test should demonstrate how to use the unit, and what the unit can do. Keep these tests enabled so that they run on every code push.

NOTE: The reason you disabled the first set of test is to allow refactoring work to occur. An active test is a code coupling. It prevents future modification of the code it's testing. You only want this for your interfaces and interaction contracts.

Comment: You make it sound like if you don't explicitly test private methods in isolation, they aren't covered by your tests and you can't trust them to work. I claim this is simply wrong. A private method (or any code path in it) that cannot be tested via a public method is dead code and should be removed. The whole point of TDD is to get full coverage by only testing public methods, because you write 0 LoC that don't exist to make a test pass. Testing an isolated private method serves ONLY to make refactoring harder, the very opposite of (one of) the goal(s) of TDD.

Comment: @kai I explicitly state that you should not have automated tests for private methods, but it is sometimes valuable to have isolated tests to help you with implementation. Those tests should not be a part of your test suite, or should be disabled for the very reason you mentioned: refactoring. It is up to your own confidence level to decide when you prefer having a programmatic test for implementing a private method or not. Maybe you did not read till the end of my answer?

Comment: you make the claim that "there's also good reason to test private methods, as to assert our implementation works". I see no basis for this in the post. there is nothing a test of a private method could tell you about working implementation that a test of a public method couldn't also tell you. The private method either works, or it doesn't. If it doesn't work it'll make a test of one or more public methods fail or it's dead and/or untested code.

Comment: @kai You mention: "or it's dead and/or untested code". Untested code is what I'm talking about. A private method could hide a lot of bugs to which the edge cases are not being exercised from the public methods. Imagine an off by one error. Sometimes, the invariants of the public methods make it so this case will never happen. In such a case, I'd consider the private method to still be buggy and have a flawed implementation, yet, its integration prevents the bug from being found and caught. In this case, you might want a few tests to try edge cases so you can be sure your method is bug free.

Comment: @kai But, understand that those tests I'm talking about are not your test suite, this is not TDD. I'm saying that, some private methods are made easier to implement if you can quickly run some tests against them. In languages with a REPL, you don't need that as much. And you can try to step through the method in your head, but I'm recommending computer ran tests instead for only the difficult to implement private methods. I suggest deleting the tests afterwards, or keeping them disabled or in it's own special place that's not run in your CI build.

Comment: I guess it kind of comes down to your workflow, but I think that in most cases you should be able to trust your tests to cover the desired behavior of the class. If you then can delete code without breaking any test (unit- or integration) then it's OK to just delete the code without writing a test to prove it's buggy, since the code should never have been written in the first place. This assumes you have decent test coverage though and I realize there are scenarios where this can't be (easily) done

Comment: @kai It's not always true you can delete the code. My off by one error is a good example. It's the same code that deals with all cases, but only the edge case would reveal a flaw in its implementation. It's not always obvious to indirectly tests those edge cases, as you need to understand what input to other functions would cause the edge input to the private one. Sometimes, it's impossible, but then, someone comes in and changes the class behavior, assumes the private method to work, and suddenly, the edge case is made possible, and a bug has swooped in.

Comment: @kai In terms of TDD tests, I believe we agree 100%. I was trying to make a distinction between testing, manual testing, automated testing and repeatable testing. The goal of testing is to assert things work. Automation can help assert that with higher confidence then manual. Repeatable tests, which is what TDD is about, has a different goal, it must assert that reusable units of code did not change behavior. This is why I mention the two class of tests: Regression and Assertion. Automation is orthogonal to both of these, and I hope my answer makes that clear.

Answer (score 4):

No, you shouldn't test private methods (how would you anyway without using something horrible like reflection). With protected methods it is slightly less obvious in C# you can make things protected internal and I think it is OK to do that to test derived classes that implement all of their functionality through template pattern methods.

But, in general, if you think that your public methods are doing too much then it is time to refactor your classes into more atomic classes and then test those clases.

Answer (score 2):

I too agree with @kwbeam's answer about not testing private methods. However, an important point I'd like to highlight - protected methods ARE part of a class' exported API and hence MUST be tested.

Protected methods may not be publicly accessible but you definitely are providing a way for sub-classes to use/override them. Something outside the class can access them and hence you need to ensure that those protected members behave in an expected manner. So don't test private methods, but do test public and protected methods.

If you believe you have a private method which contains critical logic, I'd try to extract it out into a separate object, isolate it and provide a way to test its behavior.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everyone else: The answer to your question is 'no'.

Indeed you are entirely correct with your approach and your thoughts, especially about code coverage.

I would also add that the question (and the answer 'no') also applies to public methods that you might introduce to classes.

- If you add methods (public/protected or private) because they make a failing test pass, then you've more or less achieved the goal of TDD.
- If you add methods (public/protected or private) because you just decide to, violating TDD, then your code coverage should catch these and you should be able to improve your process.

Also, for C++ (and I should think only for C++) I implement interfaces using private methods only, to indicate that the class should only be used via the interface it implements.  It stops me mistakenly calling new methods added to my implementation from my tests

Answer (score 1):

If you are aiming high code coverage (I suggest you should), you should test your all methods regardless of they are private or protected.

Protected is a kind of different discussion point, but in summary, it should not be there at all. Either it breaks encapsulation on deployed code, or it forces you to inherit from that class, just to unit test it, even sometimes you do not need to inherit.

Just hiding a method to client (making private) does not give it to have privilege not to be audited. Therefore, they can be tested by public methods as mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

A good design means splitting the application into multiple testable units. After doing this, some units are exposed to the public API, but some others may not be. Also, the interaction points between exposed units and these "internal" units are also not a part of the pubic API.

I think once we have the identifiable unit, is would benefit from the unit tests, regardless if exposed via public API or not.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - NO.

Explanation :
why should test a private function ? It will automatically be tested anyway (and must be tested) when you test the feature/method which is using it - the private function.