# Applying tests for superclass on derived class

Tags: c++, testing, derived-class, googletest

Say you have a C++ class `B` derived of class `A`. You have extensive tests set up for class `A` that you would also like to run over instances of class `B`, as it should fully support `A`'s functionality. Of course you also have additional `B` specific tests.

How would you setup the tests so that you don't have to duplicate all of `A`'s tests for `B`?

A specific answer for [Google Test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) would be great.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615274/how-do-unit-tests-change-when-a-base-class-is-driven-out) is very similar - might be useful to you.

Comment: Base/derived (prefered), parent/child or super-/sub- class. Pick one pair!

Answer (score 2):

Use [Typed Tests](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Typed_Tests) (if you know in advance which types you want to test) or [Type-Parameterized Tests](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Type-Parameterized_Tests) (if you want to decouple fixture creation from test logic).