# Private accessor won't access private member

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, private-members

In my class, to test, I have a private boolean instance variable and a method to access it:

```
MyClass()
{
    private volatile bool b;
    public MyMethod()
    {
         b = false;
    }
}
```

After creating a unit test for the method

```
[TestMethod()]
public void MyMethodTest()
{
      PrivateObject param0 = new PrivateObject(new MyClass());
      MyClass_Accessor target = new MyClass_Accessor(param0);
      target.b = false;
}
```

I get this error:

```
Property, indexer, or event 'property' is not supported by the language; try directly
calling accessor method 'accessor_taketh' 'accessor_giveth'
```

but there are no methods like this in the accessor object, instead there is

```
[Shadowing("b")]
public bool b{ get; set; }
```

So why do I get the error?

Comment: You asked the same question a few minutes ago and deleted. Why are you asking again?

Comment: sorry for that, i thought i got the error but i was wrong it still exists

Comment: what is a `PrivateObject` and `MyClass_Accessor`?

Comment: have you studied the [compiler error information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw0xhhzy(VS.80).aspx)?

Comment: you say your `bool b` is global, but it's not global in the code you are showing. are you really posting all your code?

Comment: its visible in the complete class scope

Comment: you are right its not static, its class variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
 param0.SetField("b", false);
```

Comment: Except that unit tests **unit tests should never directly access object internals**. This creates a rigid structure and leads to convoluted code. Tests [should exercise objects through their public interface](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5601730/1106367) exclusively.