# AngularJS unit test controller with only private functions

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have following controller that has only private functions. I am struggling to test this controller. Shall I test if it is doing $emit, since the ImageService has been tested? How do I test $emit in this case? Or shall I test if it is calling the ImageService.fetchImageStacks method? In this case, how do I trigger init function?

```
(function (angular, global, undefined) {
'use strict';

var ImageController = {};

ImageController.$inject = [
    '$rootScope',
    '$log',
    'ImageService'
];

ImageController = function (
    $rootScope,
    $log,
    ImageService
) {

    var getImageStacks = function() {
        ImageService
            .fetchImageStacks()
            .success(function (result) {
                ImageService.setImageStacks(result);
                $rootScope.$emit('rootScope:imageStacksUpdated', result);
            })
            .error(function (){
                $log.error('Failed to get imageStackInfo file.');
            });
    };

    var init = function () {
        getImageStacks();
    };

    init();

    return {
        getImageStacks: getImageStacks
    };
}

angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('ImageController', ImageController);

})(angular, this);
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be testing private/internal methods that are not available to the outside world(*imho*).

Some resources on the subject (for & against):

- http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/05/31/my-take-on-unit-testing-private-methods/
- http://www.quora.com/Should-you-unit-test-private-methods-on-a-class
- http://henrikwarne.com/2014/02/09/unit-testing-private-methods/
- [Should Private/Protected methods be under unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601730/should-private-protected-methods-be-under-unit-test)
- [Should I test private methods or only public ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105007/should-i-test-private-methods-or-only-public-ones)

---

With that said, you are exposing `getImageStacks` on the controller - so it isn't a private method. If you were to log out the result of instantiating the controller in your test suite, you should see something of the sort:

`{ getImageStacks: function }`

*(`init()` in your case, is just an alias for `getImageStacks` (aka there is no need for the `init` method - you could just call `getImageStacks` and be done with it)).*

**Anyway, to write some tests;**

First of, you should `stub` out the `ImageService` as we are not interested in the internal implementation of said service, we are only ever interested in the communication going from the controller to the service. A great library for stubbing/mocking/spying is [sinonjs](http://sinonjs.org) - get it, you won't regret it.

In the `beforeEach` I would suggest you do something like this:

```
// Stub out the ImageService
var ImageService = {
  fetchImageStacks: sinon.stub(),
  setImageStacks: sinon.stub()
};

var $scope, instantiateController;

beforeEach(function () {
  // Override the ImageService residing in 'your_module_name'
  module('your_module_name', function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('ImageService', ImageService);
  });

  // Setup a method for instantiating your controller on a per-spec basis.
  instantiateController = inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $injector) {
    ctrl = $controller('ImageController', {
      $scope: $rootScope.$new(),
      // Inject the stubbed out ImageService.
      ImageService: $injector.get('ImageService')
    });
  });
});
```

Now you have a stubbed out ImageService to test calls against, and a method to instantiate your controller with the dependencies passed into it.

Some example specs you can run;

```
it('calls the ImageService.fetchImageStacks method on init', function () {
  instantiateController();
  expect(ImageService.fetchImageStacks).to.have.been.calledOnce;
});

it('calls the ImageService.setImageStacks on success', inject(function ($q, $timeout) {
  ImageService.getImageStacks.returns($q.when('value'));
  instantiateController();
  $timeout.flush();
  expect(ImageService.setImageStacks).to.have.been.calledOnce.and.calledWith('value');
}));
```

I hope that will suffice and answer your questions on;

- If/when you should/shouldn't test internal implementation.
- How to test the initialisation of the controller.
- How to test methods of an injected service.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of some help!