# Is it a good approach to override methods in a class which you don't want to test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, tdd

Suppose my class has 3 methods:

```
public void parent() throws Exception {}
public String child_1(String arg_1) throws IOException {}
public boolean child_2(String arg_1, String arg_2) throws SQLException {}
```

`parent()` calls `child_1()` and `child_2()`, like:

```
public void parent() throws Exception {
    // Do some complicated stuff

    child_1("str1");

    // More stuff

    child_2("str1", "str2");

    // More stuff
}
```

**Now, if I have already tested child_1() and child_2() and I want to test only parent(), is it ok to override child_1() and child_2() and test only parent()?** Something like this:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass() {
    @Override
    public String child_1(String arg_1) throws IOException {
        return "expected_string_to continue_execution";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean child_2(String arg_1, String arg_2) throws SQLException {
        return true;    // return expected boolean result to continueexecution;
    }
};

myClass.parent();
```

By doing this, I can easily test my parent() and since child_1() and child_2() are already tested in other unit tests for this class, it does not do any cheating (atleast that's what I think, please correct me if I am wrong). Also, in real world, if chaild_1() and child_2() are doing something complicated, this approach makes testing easy, we do not redundantly check time consuming code.

***My question is, whether it is a right approach? If not, what is the downside and most importantly, what is the right approach?*** If someone can explain with the same above example, that will be awesome.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If chald_1() and child_2() are doing something really complicated (like db access, etc), I would refactor them to be separate classes and inject them as dependencies... then you can mock them in unit your test.

Comment: ok, i think i gave a wrong example by saying db access. what is there is no db access? i will update the question so that i does not go on the 'db access' road.

Comment: What does parent() do? If it's just used to call child1 and child2 in a specific order, I would use JUnit features to do that (@Before/@After, etc).  


If not, I would check parent() as well.  


If child1 & child2 are only run by parent and you're worried about the performances, just test parent:  


    public void testParentLinear() {
        Assert.assertEquals(child1(), f);

        Bar c2 = child2();
        Assert...
    }
    void testParentConditionOne(){}


That way you can test parent(), if it gets more complicated (conditional calling of chidl1/child2) you could test the outcomes.

Comment: An additional note I would suggest is that a unit test should allow for refactoring without failing if the refactor does not change behavior. Overriding would violate this principal because you are locking down the implementation of the class to call public methods. What if the class were refactored so that `child_1` and `parent` both call some other `private` method. The test should still pass but overriding would cause it to fail.

Answer (score 3):

I would say overriding methods is something you should avoid in general since it most likely violates the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Test code is no special: it should follow the same strict principles as production code. The only exception I can think of is if you are testing legacy code with high coupling between components and overriding is the only option. But when writing new code I don't see any reason.

I think @samlewis is on to something: if you feel you want to test `parent()` in isolation for some reason, then `child_1()` and `child_2()` should probably be in own classes that are injected into `parent()`. Avoid testing anything smaller than a class. If you need to test something smaller you probably have a responsibility that wants to be extracted ([Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

A hint that `child_1()` and `child_2()` actually belongs in other classes is that they are public and that the public method `parent()` calls it. Public methods should typically only call non-public methods (although there are probably exceptions).

Or did you make the child methods public so that you can test them? If so, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105007/should-i-test-private-methods-or-only-public-ones/105021#105021).

Answer (score 1):

Are `child_1()` and `child_2()` really consumed from the outside, or did you make them public so you could test them ?

As Torbjörn points out, it's rare to see a public method calling 2 other public methods on the same instance. Submethods typically contain behavior that is internal to a class and shouldn't be exposed to the world. Their names often reflect another level of language than the public facing contracts of the class - they are expressed in the object's own private jargon.

Assuming you can make `child_1()` and `child_2()` private, you don't have to test them explicitly, they will be tested indirectly by the `parent()` test.