# Should java/scala test packages follow the structure as main regarding inverted domain prefix?

Tags: java, scala, naming-conventions

The convention for java and scala in `main` package is:

```plaintext
  main/
    java-or-scala/
      inverted.domain.convetion/
        foo/
```

What about the `test` package? Is there a convention? Should it be:

```plaintext
  test/
   java-or-scala/
      inverted.domain.convetion
        fooTest/
```

or can it be:

```plaintext
  test/
   java-or-scala/
        fooTest/
```

?

Comment: it should be the same. espacially if you want to measure the code coverage it must be the same

Comment: thanks, @Jens. Is it because converge tools expect it to be this way? Do maven and sbt also expect it to be the same in the test package? Thanks, again.

Comment: It is the coverage tool. maven doesn't need the same structure

Comment: It is a good idea to test classes to be in the same package as the classes they are testing.

Comment: Also if you want to test a private method in package `com.foo.bar`, you can use `private[bar]` to make it accessible in `com.foo.bar` package in your unit tests.

Comment: Hey, @Ava, that's interesting. Can you please point me to some resource about it, so I can learn more? Thank you.

Comment: For scopes in Scala: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-control-scala-method-scope-object-private-package/. Regarding the use case that I've mentioned the easiest way is to test it yourself or refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21369609/9134945.

Comment: Good resource. Thanks