# Access private method having parameter with private access specifier

Tags: java, junit

I am writing a **Junit** for a method with multiple parameters and having **private access specifier**. I am using Java reflection to achieve this. However, one of the parameter for this private method is private class. I am doing below:

```
ClassHavingPrivateMethod object = new ClassHavingPrivateMethod();
object.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(PRIVATE_METHOD_NAME, Param1.class, <This parameter is a private class Inside ClassHavingPrivateMethod>)
```

How can I proceed?

**EDIT**

I agree on the point that I should not write a test case for a private method with reflection and it should always be accessed through a wrapper public method. However, is there any way to achieve the above objective through reflection. Even though, I am not going to write my test case through reflection but I am eager to know about it.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to test private methods? Can't they be exercised through the public API?

Comment: Be careful when testing private methods. You'll quickly end up testing the implementation rather than the behaviour.

Comment: Here is some discussion if private methods should be tested directly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105007/should-i-test-private-methods-or-only-public-ones?lq=1

Comment: @Thilo : Yes, there is a wrapper public method for this private method. But If i try to call this wrapper, I have to do a lot of extra set up and that is not inside my JUnit testing scope. Actually, this method is inside a JmsListner onMessage() method. This onMessage() is public method.

Comment: @NilsH Thanks for the suggestion, I will keep it in mind.

Comment: " I have to do a lot of extra set up and that is not inside my JUnit testing scope.". That is a common problem. Ideally, these "glue" classes (like the JmsListener) don't do much themselves and just act as facades to otherwise testable code. Real-life is seldom ideal, though. Maybe the class can be refactored so that the "juicy parts" that you want to test are package-private? Then they are still hidden from the public interface but accessible to unit tests?

Answer (score 2):

One of the way you can try by changing the access from **private** to **default**. By changing the access level to default the method can be accessed only from the same package (still restricted access) on the other hand since your **test class and class under test will be under same package** , the test class can call that method directly, without doing any trick.

**Example :**

```html
package com.test;

class SomeClass {
  String defaultMethod(){
   ...
  }
}


package com.test;

class SomeClassTest {
  public void testDefaultMethod(){
    SomeClass testObject = new SomeClass();
    testObject.defaultMethod();
  }
}
```

Hope it will help.