# Java: Unit test design

Tags: java, junit

I have implemented a method `getUsers()`, which basically construct a `List<ShoppingCart>`, then create a `List<User>`:

```
public List<User> getUsers() {
   // construct a liste of List<ShoppingCart>
   ....
   // update 
   ...
}
```

The construction of `List<ShoppingCart>` contains a lot of logic, so I decided to move those code out and create a private method:

```
public List<User> getUsers() {
   // construct a liste of List<ShoppingCart>
   List<ShoppingCart> shoppingList = getShoppingList();
   // update 
   ...
}

private List<ShoppingCart> getShoppingList() {
  ...
}
```

Now I need to unit test `getUsers()`. But I realized that I have difficulty to get the `List<ShoppingCart>` because it's a private method. 
And I don't want to make `getShoppingList()` public because I don't need it anywhere else.

I think there is a design problem in my code, what is the best way to unit test these kinds of methods containing returned value of private methods ?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

No it's not the same question as [Java test class with many private methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969920/java-test-class-with-many-private-methods), my question is not if it's necessary to test private method, but what should be a better design

Comment: are you mocking `getShoppingList` while writing test cases for `getUsers`?

Comment: Why do you need to get shoppingList in your test ? Also, why do you create the list on the fly in the method and not outside ?

Comment: Good option: move getShoppingList to diferent class, and then mock it

Comment: @Deadpool it's private method you can't mock it (in fact you can, but i don't think it's best option)

Comment: This answer fits in your place https://stackoverflow.com/a/27969999/9959152

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think good option is separate logic for user and shopping cards. If You agree with me, You can move shopping cards logic to different class, and then You can mock this logic on Your test and then write test for `getUsers()` like this:

```
public class UserTest {

 @Mock
 private ShoppingCard shoppingCard;
 private User sut = new User();

 @Before
 public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
 }


 @Test
 public void shouldReturnUsersEmptyListWhenCardsEmpty(){
    //given
    when(shoppingCard.getShoppingCards()).thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());

    //when
    final List<User> result = sut.getUsers();

    //then
    assertEquals(0, result.size());
 }
}
```

Comment: I think you are right

Answer (score 2):

In the end, this is about balancing "purity" against, well, the "real world"?!

Meaning: if you insist on having a **private** method, then that prevents you from doing partial mocking for example. And it prevents you from directly testing the method.

Personally, I sometimes go pragmatic in such situations: simply by making that other method *package protected* (instead of private). Then you can access it from unit tests, and when necessary, use a Mockito spy to partially mock out such methods.

The "real world" design solution: consider if "getting the shopping list" isn't something that is worth to stand completely **on its own**. Actually, it sounds rather odd that such a "complex" activity ... sits somewhere as a private method. The consequence of doing so might be: you start duplicating code. If there is **one** central service (class) that gets you "the shopping list", then any code that needs that list ... can get it from there.

Answer (score 0):

If a method should be private, it shouldn't be unit tested. This leaves you with 2 options:

- Make `getShoppingList()` public
- Don't unit test `getShoppingList()`

If the correctness of `getShoppingList()` is fundamentally required for your entire application to work, you should make it public and create unit tests for it.

If, however, it is only called by code that then processes it, and those methods are user-facing, you can simply test those methods and ensure they behave as expected. This then passively guarantees that `getShoppingList()` works as expected.

Imagine you had an error that made `getShoppingList()` throw some kind of exception. Then, in your test for `getUsers()` you should see that exception thrown anyway (assuming it calls `getShoppingList()`.