# C++ / GoogleTest - How to test member variable of a class being tested

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm creating tests for a legacy code and wondering if it is possible to check the values of member variables of a class like this (I know my code below is very lousy, bad example :/. Hope to just please focus on the question):

```
class Animal
{
public:
   RESULT getInfo();
   int age_;
};

int main()
{
   Animal animal;
   RESULT result = animal.getInfo();

   return 0;
}

RESULT Animal::getInfo()
{
    age_ = rand() % 10 + 1;
    if (age == 5)
    {
        return success;
    }
    else
    {
        return fail;
    }       
}
```

And in my test (using Google Test), I call getInfo():

```
EXPECT_EQ(success, sut_->getInfo());
```

However, this just verifies that the result of `getInfo()` is `success`.  Is there any other way for me to check the value of `age_` without adding a new method/changing the return value?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way of testing private methods with GoogleTest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354280/what-is-the-best-way-of-testing-private-methods-with-googletest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have already made `age_` public, you can just add another `EXPECT_EQ` statement. If making `age_` public was not intentional then you will have to come with a method to access `age_` in `GTest` code.