# Method under test calling private void method which I'd also like to include in my test

Tags: java, exception, junit, junit4

I've a JUnit which I want to use to test for exceptions. It's like this:

```
@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {
  boolean testPass;
  try {
    method1();
    testPass = true;
    Assert.assertTrue(testPass);
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    testPass = false;
    Assert.assertTrue(testPass);
  }
  System.out.println("End of test2 Junit");
}
```

`method1()` is like this:

```
public void method1() throws Exception {
  try {
    do something....
    method2();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
  } finally {
   do some more...
  }
}
```

For what I want, my test is fine when just considering `method1().` My problem is that `method2()` is called by `method1()` and can also throw an exception. It's like this:

```
private  void method2() throws Exception {
  if (confition is not met) {
    do something...
    throw new Exception();
  } else {
    do something else;
  }
}
```

It's possible that no exception is thrown by `method1()` but then gets thrown by `method2()`. I'd like my test to check for an exception from either but I'm not sure how to factor method2() into my test, especially as it's a `private void` method. Can this be done and if so, how?

Comment: What do you mean `factor method2() into my test`? Do you want to test logic of `method2()` along with `method1()` or not?

Comment: If its possible, all I want is for an assertTrue to pass if no exception is thrown in either `method1()` or `method2()` and for it to fail if an exception is thrown by either `method1()` or `method2()`.

Comment: In that case your test will fail if `method2()` throws `Exception` or any of its subclasses.

Comment: You should be testing the *public* interface, not private implementation. Unit testing should be black-box, in that the tests focus on what occurs from a user perspective. Since the user can't call `method2()`, there should be no reason to test it. The tests exists to ensure the implementation gives excepted results. If `method2()` throws an exception which `method1()` swallows, then the user shouldn't be aware of that exception in the first place. Why are you testing for it? Did you leak details of `method2()` into the contract of `method1()`? If so, THAT'S the problem.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks for that.

Comment: No problem. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105007/should-i-test-private-methods-or-only-public-ones) & [this](https://www.quora.com/Should-you-unit-test-private-methods-on-a-class)

Comment: Great. I'll have a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code it is possible only if you can achieve true condition in this `if`:

```
  if (condition is not met) {
    do something...
    throw new Exception();
  } else {
    do something else;
  }
```

If for some reasons you couldn't prepare such kind of condition in the unit tests (say, Internet connection is needed) you may extract the condition checking into new method:

```
  if (isNotCondition()) {
    do something...
    throw new Exception();
```

In the test class you override new method and return what you want:

```
MyService myService = new MyService() {
    @Override
    boolean isNotCondition() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is more compact way to test exceptional cases:

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void testMethod1WhenMethod2ThrowsException() throws Exception {
    thrown.expect(Exception.class);
    thrown.expectMessage("expected exception message");

    myServive.method1();
}
```