# rspec private method instance validation testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

There is a private method with the following code.

```
attr_reader :some_variable

validate :some_def

def some_def
  unless some_variable.valid?
    some_variable.errors.messages.each do |message|
      errors.add(:some_variable, message)
  end
end
```

I am new to rspec and not familiar with private method testing. Any help is appreciated.

I need to cover the lines of the private method.

Comment: It looks like validation testing - https://makandracards.com/makandra/38645-testing-activerecord-validations-with-rspec

Comment: Hi, I already went through the link, but am not able to understand that. If you could please explain how. Thanks.

Comment: IMO you can: initialize the object, set `some_variable` value as invalid and then call `valid?` on the object you initialized (it should return `false`). Then, repeat the same but set the correct value for `some_variable` and check if you get `true` when calling `valid?`

Comment: Writing test for private method is not a good practice. Checkout interesting post https://stackoverflow.com/a/105021/398863

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
describe 'validations' do
  let(:some_variable_object) { SomeVariable.new } 
  let(:new_foo) { described_class.new(some_variable: some_variable_object) }

  context 'when some_variable is valid' do
    before do
      allow(some_variable_object).to receive(:valid?) { true }
    end

    it 'is valid' do
     expect(new_foo).to be_valid
    end

    it 'does not have errors related to some_variable' do
      expect(new_foo.errors[:some_variables]).to be_empty
    end
  end
```

then you can do the same to test the opposite, when `some_variable` is not valid...
now, there are tools to help you setting up objects within the spec easily (FactoryBot).

Comment: What does `SomeVariable` here `let(:some_variable_object) { SomeVariable.new } `  means? like the same instance variable? if so if it was capitalized, it will through uninitialized error right?