# How to test private/internal extension methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, access-levels

I have an `internal` extension method:

```
@VisibleForTesting
internal fun URL.normalizeUrl() {some code not related to this question}
```

I want to test this method in a JUnit test

```
val normalizedUrl = someUrl.normalizeUrl()
```

But the method is invisible for the test class, I get `Unresolved reference: normalizeUrl` in IntelliJ.

Is this possible to test this method without modifying the access level?

Comment: Is your code testing located in a different module? If yes, could you move that code into the module where `normalizeUrl` is defined?

Comment: @Lino-Votedon'tsayThanks nope, the code is in the same module as tests. Code is under `src/main/java/some/package` and tests are under `/src/test/java/some/package`

Comment: One philosophy of testing is that you should not test the "private" implementation, you should only test what's publicly observable. That way the tests are less likely to break when the implementation changes because it's optimized, or refactored to add support for a new feature.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105007/should-i-test-private-methods-or-only-public-ones