# How to unit test an internal method or private method in an abstract class in c#?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have to write a unit test for an internal or private method in an abstract class in c#.
consider this:

```
Public Abstract Class MyAbstractClass
{
 Private String MyMethod()
 {
   //Do Something
   return "HI";
 }
}
```

And, my test method:

```
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    var testProcessor = new Mock<MyAbstractClass>
    {
        CallBase = true
    };
    var privateType = new PrivateType(typeof(MyAbstractClass));
    PrivateObject privateObject = new PrivateObject(testProcessor , privateType);
    var resValue = (String)privateObject.Invoke("MyMethod");
    Assert.AreEqual(resValue ,"HI");
}
```

but when I run the test method, I'm getting below error:

```
 System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.
```

How to resolve that?

Comment: Why do you need to test an abstract class. It's uninstantiable. You can't be using it directly in your code. Test the derived classes that your code used

Comment: If you are using `Moq` you should likely pass the mocked instance and not the mocking wrapper... 
So: `PrivateObject privateObject = new PrivateObject(testProcessor.Object , privateType);`
is perhaps what you want.

Comment: By the way: Using a mocked instance of your abstract class you don't test that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) as a mocking tool, the exception shown results of passing `testProcessor` instead of `testProcessor.Object`. If you change that line to...

```
PrivateObject privateObject = new PrivateObject(testProcessor.Object, privateType);
```

...you'll get rid of this error.
This is how it should work (in NET Framework, PrivateObject and such like has not been ported to NET Core MSTest):

```
//productive code
    public abstract class MyAbstractClass
    {
        private string MyMethod()
        {
            //Do Something
            return "HI";
        }
    }

    //testproject

    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var testProcessor         = new Moq.Mock<MyAbstractClass>();
            var privateType           = new PrivateType(typeof(MyAbstractClass));
            var privateObject         = new PrivateObject(testProcessor.Object, privateType);
            var resValue              = (string)privateObject.Invoke("MyMethod");
            Assert.AreEqual(resValue, "HI");
        }
    }
```

By the way, I' didn't know a mock of an abstract class will execute the implementation of the abstract class. I thought it would create stubs that return defaults, as a mock of an interface does. 
 Interesting feature...

Comment: Thanks lidqy! that was my solution. Yeah with Moq we don't need to create a derived class from abstract class. it handles everything. I just did not know that I need to use Object here. I tried it for typeof(MyAbstractClass) but it was not the right place. anter changing the privateObject, it was resolved! good catch!

Answer (score 4):

You should not be testing private methods:

> I do not unit test private methods. A private method is an
> implementation detail that should be hidden to the users of the class.
> Testing private methods breaks encapsulation.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105007/should-i-test-private-methods-or-only-public-ones) for more details.

As Flydog57 says, you should be testing a derived class (not the abstract one).

You can do this easily by creating a private test class inside your test class, and use this private class in your tests.

```
private class MyConcreteTestClass : MyAbstractClass 
{
     public string SomeMethodThatCallsMethodInAbstractClass()
     {
          ....
     }
}

public void MyTestMethod()
{
    // Arrange
    var testProcessor = new MyConcreteTestClass();

    // Act
    var result = testProcessor.SomeMethodThatCallsMethodInAbstractClass();

    // Asset
    Assert.AreEqual(result ,"HI");
}
```

Comment: Yeah it seems the right solution, but with Moq we don't need to do that. Moq handles everything. more discussion below (@lidqy)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `BindingFlags` to be `NonPublic` in order to find the private method.

I am not sure what is the `PrivateObject` but this should work (you may change it a little bit to make it suitable for your needs):

```
Type type = typeof(MyAbstractClass);

MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(
    methodName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

string result = (string)method.Invoke("MyMethod", null);
```