# Unit testing private methods

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, python-unittest

Several questions, such as [Should I test private methods or only public ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105007/should-i-test-private-methods-or-only-public-ones) seem to encourage testing private methods through the public interfaces because:

> You test the private methods, by writing through tests of your public methods.

Because I was starting a new project, I decided to go with the best practices, so I had a validate function:

```
def validate(self, otherArgs, ...):
  self._validateOneThing(args)
  self._validateAnotherThing(args)
  ...
```

So instead of testing `_validateOneThing` and `_validateAnotherThing` directly, I tested them through the public interface - the `validate` function. Note that only the `validate` function, and not the other functions, should be called by other classes.

- The first "problem" I've encountered is that testing private methods through the public methods requires dummy inputs for other non-testable parts. Consider this example:

  ```
  def validate(self, files, format, dataType):
    self._validateDatatype(dataType)
  ```

  What would a test for the `_validateDatatype` function look?

  ```
  def test_validateDataType(self):
      validator = Validator()
      with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
        validator.validate("dummy1", "C", "dummy2")
  ```

  At this point, I didn't yet know for sure what kinds of inputs I would want `files` and `dataType` to be, so I just put random values.

  But then, in the future I created a function to also validate the format. So this causes all the other tests that I did for the datatype to fail. Why? Because, indeed, the format cannot be `"dummy2"`; it has to be something else. So, now, I had to go and change all my tests.

  In a large codebase, I reckon that this could yield several working time hours to fix.

  Now, if I only tested the private methods, I just needed to input what the function actually *needed* and not other components that are unnecessary for that function.
- The second thing that occurred was when I had to test if a file existed in the file system.

  So I created a function `_validateFile`, which contained a `os.path.exists(myFile)` inside. Following good testing practices, I should not rely on file system events, so I created a mock for some tests:

  ```
  @patch('os.path.exists', return_value=True)
  ```

  This means that for every call to `os.path.exists`, it yield `True`.

  But now I need to apply this mock to *every* other test, because I've been writing `"dummy1"`, `"dummy2"` as files and they certainly do not exist. Alright, but what if I have several `os.path.exists` inside the validation but in several different functions, how do I control each `os.path.exists` for each function, unless I do it manually? I can't. And if it is on a loop, then forget it.

I'm trying to understand how unit testing only the public interfaces is superior to the private methods, but it is just giving me so many problems and I'm spending much more time modifying the tests for it to be worth it. Please give me any guidance here.

Comment: This is going to depend on context, it's hard to be specific from such a vague example. It seems like you're writing code before thinking through what it should actually be doing (why define parameters if you don't know what they should be?), which makes it hard to write good tests, and ignoring signs that the thing you're testing has too many concerns. The _purpose_ of the guidance is to allow you to confidently refactor the code, rather than having to change the tests for every implementation change.

Comment: You should see best practices as a general guideline. They are not always the best thing for your specific use case and can be broken. More often than not, I also test my private methods separately. On a sidenote, I would suggest [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) and [mypy](https://mypy-lang.org/) for static type checking in python.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  >why define parameters if you don't know what they should be?  That's not the point. In an agile, environment things change.

Comment: _"I just put random values"_ isn't agility, though. Presumably you have some idea of the requirements for `validate` (and it's unlikely that `files` should be anything even _like_ `"dummy1"`, aside from the plural suggesting a sequence or iterable), but we don't.

Comment: @jonrsharpe again, Sure, files will never be something like "dymmy1", it will be something like ["file1.txt","file2.txt"]...or maybe it won't! In my specific case, the file needs to exist in the filesystem, so the only possible values are files that exist. However, at the start, the part wasn't done.

Comment: Do you plan EVERYTHING before coding, like every possible case, every possible edge case, because from what you've said, I seem to be doing that wrong. Sure, I agree that there should be some kind of requirements, but requiring me to write down EVERY little detail of the program before writing it just seems like a waste of time to me.

Comment: No, I don't plan everything, but I test drive so need _some_ concrete idea what to pass. _"In my specific case, the file needs to exist in the filesystem, so the only possible values are files that exist"_ - so maybe the default should be the path to a [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html)? You can abstract this away (e.g. using [pytest fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html)) so that tests where the specific value isn't relevant just use "a valid value", then if the nature of the valid value changes you only change it once for all tests using it.